# Keyboard not showing when being prompted by UITextField

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, ios-simulator

In iOS 13.2, I'm noticing that my keyboard no longer shows up in my apps on the simulator and a real device. When I tap inside a UITextField, nothing happens but the cursor blinking inside the textfield. Is anyone else having this problem or know how to solve?

**UPDATE**

The problem originates from removing storyboard files and initiating a rootViewController programmatically

```
        var windowScene = new UIWindowScene(session, connectionOptions);
        Window = new UIWindow(windowScene);

        Window.RootViewController = new ViewController();
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

After that, I just noticed the keyboard doesn't show again in a new project.

Comment: have you use any keyboard notification or custom class ?

Comment: Do you have any [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi , if answer be helpful , thanks for marking or voting up it in advance.  *.^

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug when you try use a programatic approach to setting a rootViewController in the new SceneDelegate opposed to how we used to in AppDelegate.

I got around this by keeping the dumb storyboard which sets the rootViewController inside and keeping SceneDelegate.cs clean for the moment and my keyboard works again. Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Glad hear that ! *.^

Comment: it must be that, but I have completely removed the storyboard stuff already. How could I add storyboard, then set the new rootViewController?

Answer (score -1):

set textfiled delegate.

```
@IBOutlet weak var urlTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.urlTextField.delegate = self // urlTextField it is your textfield outlet 
}
```

If you delete this line of code, the keyboard does not appear, but if this exists, the keyboard does come up.

Answer (score -1):

**About simulator** : You can check **setting** in iOS simulator firsrt .

Have a look at this screenshot ,be sure **Use Hardware Keyboard** not be selected . Or you can select it and unselect it again , then keyboard will show.

[image]

Restart app to check whether keyboard can be shown.

[image]